# Counting in nested mysql queries

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a prepared MySQL query as follows. Suppose members of team1 (first table) playing a specific 'game' ('game' is an entry of team1) can also be members of team2 (second table). I want to get the number of members of team1 playing 'game' that are not of members of team2. But I don't know where I am going wrong because the query fails:

```
SELECT game, member 
FROM team2 
WHERE game = :game and member 
NOT IN (SELECT member FROM team1 WHERE game = :game)
```

Comment: can you make clearer what your table structure is?

Comment: can u tell me what means `game = :game` ?

Comment: @goodmood Probably he is using PHP with PDO. This is a parameter passed to SQL.

Comment: @FredWuerges +1 or maybe delphi, we don't know

Comment: please show the code, how you pass the parameters - in delphi you have to pass **2** parameters not only one although they have the same name

Comment: Semi-off-topic: it's unusual to keep separate tables for different types of the same thing. Typically, you would have a single table for all of the "games played" records, with columns "game_id", "member_id", and "team_id". This means you need only 4 tables (records, games, members, teams), which is easier to maintain than having 1 table per team (plus whatever else you have). You don't want to change your DB schema every time a team joins/leaves the league, or update n tables instead of 1 when your "teamX" schema changes. Depending on your full schema this may also reduce data duplication.

Comment: @mmitchell +1 thats why we all ask for the structure ;o)

Comment: @user1611830 please update your question: 1) what fails - error message or empty result? 2) how do you pass the parameters? (source code) 3) post table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

is little obfuscate for the sql

try this

```
   SELECT t2.game, t2.member 
   FROM team2 t2
    WHERE t2.game = :game 
   and t2.member 
     NOT IN (SELECT t1.member FROM team1 t1  WHERE t1.game = t2.game)
    order by t2.game
```

look [**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c890/2)

EDIT:

if this didnt solve your problem , (since you dont say anything what happen) .just share your whole code to see where is the problem.

Comment: i don't think so http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a0ff/1/0 - but i think it would really help in this case ;o)

Comment: he let the sqls head be in trouble of the member and game , (same column names in both tables) and he didnt disperse them , but your fiddle looks also right.

Comment: Sir Rufo's fiddle is exactly the same as the SQL code the OP provided. So looking at just the SQL, the OP's code should work. I don't know anything about Delphi but it sounds like Sir Rufo is right -- the problem is outside the code snippet provided by the poster.

Comment: @mmitchell down vote ?? , something wrong ? im gona delete it , need to go sleep better then looking to this `-1`

Comment: Maybe the downvote was a little hasty, but your answer doesn't actually address the problem the OP is having. Aliasing the tables/columns doesn't change anything in this case, so I think your answer would have been better as a comment or question edit. At any rate I can't change my vote until you edit your post. If you want to take another crack at it I'd be happy to change my vote.